# OSError: Could not find lib geos_c.dll

Tags: python, shapely, oserror

After a system re-imaging, I am seeing this error message when trying to run a script involving shapely:

```
OSError: Could not find lib geos_c.dll or load any of its variants ['C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\CS\\Library\\lib\\geos_c.dll']
```

Unlike a lot of the questions asked online, or like [this](https://github.com/conda-forge/shapely-feedstock/issues/45), for me the issue occurred not during installation, but when I actually tried to run the script.

I tried the work-around about installing OsGeo4W and adding the folder in environment variable and it did not work for me. I also tried copying geos_c.dll from `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin` into `C:\\Users\\myusername\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\envs\\CS\\Library\\lib\\`, did not work either. I ran script in cmd, Anaconda Prompt & PyCharm, and the same error message persists.

I saw [this link](https://github.com/conda-forge/shapely-feedstock/issues/55), saying it is an issue with the version of geos/shapely, but when I tried to do `conda install shapely=1.6.3`, I got this:

```
Package vc conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> vc[version='14.*|>=14,<15.0a0|>=14.1,<15.0a0']
Package geos conflicts for:
shapely=1.6.3 -> geos==3.6.2
Package vs2015_runtime conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> vs2015_runtime
Package numpy conflicts for:
shapely=1.6.3 -> numpy[version='>=1.11|>=1.8|>=1.9']
Package sqlite conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> sqlite[version='>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.26.0,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0']
Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> pip
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

I do not know what else to do, please help.
Here is the list of packages I have:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
asn1crypto                0.24.0                py36_1003    conda-forge
attrs                     19.1.0                     py_0    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.70.0               h6a4c333_2    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.6.16            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2019.6.16                py36_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.12.3           py36hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
cfitsio                   3.470                hfa6e2cd_2    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4                 py36_1003    conda-forge
click                     7.0                        py_0    conda-forge
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
cryptography              2.7              py36hb32ad35_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.65.3               h4496350_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.5             habb2df7_1003    conda-forge
fiona                     1.8.6            py36h2979200_4    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.0               h563cfd7_1    conda-forge
freexl                    1.0.5             hd288d7e_1002    conda-forge
gdal                      2.4.2            py36he6b6c38_4    conda-forge
geos                      3.7.2                he025d50_1    conda-forge
geotiff                   1.5.1                h8f84788_2    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          hb01d8f6_1002    conda-forge
glib                      2.58.3            hc0c2ac7_1002    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.13            hf8e6fe8_1002    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.5          nompi_ha405e13_1103    conda-forge
icu                       64.2                 he025d50_1    conda-forge
idna                      2.8                   py36_1000    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2019.4                      245
jpeg                      9c                hfa6e2cd_1001    conda-forge
kealib                    1.4.10            hf7dc31f_1005    conda-forge
krb5                      1.16.3            hdd46e55_1001    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0                    12_mkl    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0                    12_mkl    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.65.3               h4496350_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1             h6538335_1006    conda-forge
libgdal                   2.4.2                h2bdb96c_4    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.15              hfa6e2cd_1005    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             h4ece8bf_1010    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.8.0                    12_mkl    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.6.2             h376842a_1003    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h7602738_0    conda-forge
libpq                     11.5                 hb0bdaea_1    conda-forge
libspatialite             4.3.0a            h832c139_1029    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.8.2                h642c060_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.10            h6512ee2_1003    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.9                h9ce36c8_5    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.8.3             he025d50_1001    conda-forge
m2w64-expat               2.1.1                         2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gettext             0.19.7                        2
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libiconv            1.14                          6
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
m2w64-xz                  5.2.2                         2
mkl                       2019.4                      245
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
munch                     2.3.2                      py_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.17.2           py36hc71023c_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.3.1                hb24c2e3_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1c               hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.41              h6538335_1003    conda-forge
pip                       19.2.3                   py36_0    conda-forge
poppler                   0.67.0               h92819f6_7    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.9                         1    conda-forge
postgresql                11.5                 h06f7779_1    conda-forge
proj4                     6.1.0                hc2d0af5_2    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.19                     py36_1    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 19.0.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
python                    3.6.7             he025d50_1005    conda-forge
requests                  2.22.0                   py36_1    conda-forge
setuptools                41.2.0                   py36_0    conda-forge
shapely                   1.6.4           py36ha35856d_1006    conda-forge
six                       1.12.0                py36_1000    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.29.0               hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.9             hfa6e2cd_1002    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.25.3                   py36_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_0
wheel                     0.33.6                   py36_0    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2                   py36_1002    conda-forge
xerces-c                  3.2.2             h6538335_1004    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4             h2fa13f4_1001    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h2fa13f4_1005    conda-forge
zstd                      1.4.0                hd8a0e53_0    conda-forge
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing happened to me.
Running `conda install -c conda-forge geos=3.7.1` worked for me.
Not sure, but it might have to do with the recently uploaded version, as you can see in  https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/geos/files?version=3.7.2 there is a new version uploaded the day before yesterday.

Comment: I got this error when trying to do that:
```UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:


Package vs2015_runtime conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> vs2015_runtime
Package vc conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> vc[version='14.*|>=14,<15.0a0']
Package pip conflicts for:
python=3.6 -> pip
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.```
It is a fresh environment, do not know what is wrong.

Comment: I set channel_priority back to flexible and your suggestion works. However, all shapely, geos, gdal, libgdal installed are from the default channel not conda-forge. I guess there must be some incompatibility issues going on in conda-forge that has yet been fixed.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I met similar issues, and I used `conda install --channel conda-forge shapely` got it fixed. I am using Windows 10 64 system. I guess packages can be reinstalled through `conda-forge` chanel until it works.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while using shapely library. I solved it using "`conda install -c conda-forge geos=3.7.1`".